# Can not Update spesific row in multiple tabel with condition cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have `SubjectTutor`, `Topic`, `Lesson`, and `Question` tables. Each table has columns `id`, `user_id`, `name` and `school_id`.

I want to make function to update `user_id` in `SubjectTutor` table that will directly update row `Topic.user_id`, `Lesson.user_id`, and `Question.user_id` with `SubjectTutor.user_id`.

this is ctp file to update `SubjectTutor.user_id`:

```
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1"> Select Tutor</label>
        <?php echo($this->Form->input('SubjectTutor.user_id', array('options'=>$tutors,'div'=>false, 'label'=>false, 
        "class" => "form-control",'empty'=>'Select Tutor')));?>
    </div>
```

this is controller:

```
if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {

        if (!empty($this->request->data)) {

            if (!isset($this->request->params['_Token']['key']) || ($this->request->params['_Token']['key'] != $this->request->params['_Token']['key'])) {
                $blackHoleCallback = $this->Security->blackHoleCallback;
                $this->$blackHoleCallback();
            }
            //validate user data
            $this->SubjectTutor->set($this->request->data['SubjectTutor']);
            $this->SubjectTutor->setValidation('add');
            if(isset($this->request->data['Plan']))
            {
                $this->SubjectTutor->Plan->set($this->request->data['Plan']);
                $this->SubjectTutor->Plan->setValidation('add');
            }
            if ($this->SubjectTutor->validates()) {

            if ($this->SubjectTutor->save($this->request->data['SubjectTutor'],false)) {    

                $subject_tutor_id   =   $id;    
                $tutor_ids = $this->SubjectTutor->user_id;
                $school_ids = $this->SubjectTutor->school_id;
                $this->Topic->updateAll(array('user_id'=>$tutor_ids), array('Topic.school_id'=>$school_ids));   
                $this->Lesson->updateAll(array('user_id'=>$tutor_ids), array('Lesson.school_id'=>$school_ids)); 
                $this->Question->updateAll(array('user_id'=>$tutor_ids), array('Question.school_id'=>$school_ids)); 
                $this->Session->setFlash("Record has been updated successfully", 'admin_flash_good');
                $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'standards', 'action'=>'subject_list',$subject_detail['Subject']['standard_id']));

            } 
        } else {
                 $this->Session->setFlash(__('The Subject could not be saved. Please, try again.', true), 'admin_flash_bad');
            }
        }
    }
```

> The error is: Topic.user_id, Lesson.user_id, and Question.user_id will not updated.
>
> I have debug $tutor_ids and $school_ids are null.

Comment: Post your SubjectTutor model

Comment: okay i got it. thank youu